# Avoid resource injection from a third part plugin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, plugin

A third party plugin uses a plugin to insert a **css** in this way:

`$config->addPageAsset("..custom-theme.css");`

Where `$config` is `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config` class.

The classic css removing from xml  doesn't work with this injection.
How can I avoid this injection without overwriting the plugin method?

Comment: What does this plugin? It only adds css or maybe it does other things that you want to preserve?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hook into Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config::addPageAsset to compare the custom css whether matched or not then will not allow it to be added to pages.

1. **app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/View/Page/ConfigPlugin.php**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
           <plugin name="Vendor_Module::page_config" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\View\Page\ConfigPlugin"/>
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. **app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/View/Page/ConfigPlugin.php**

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\View\Page;

   class ConfigPlugin
   {
       public function aroundAddPageAsset(
           \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $subject,
           \Closure $proceed,
           $file,
           array $properties = [],
           $name = null
       ) {
           if ($file == '..custom-theme.css') {
               return $subject;
           }

           return $proceed($file, $properties, $name);
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this help.